# MySQL binary logging with just one log file?

Tags: mysql, binlog, mysqld

I have a MySQL database running with binary logging turned on. Each time the database is restarted a new binary log file is created in the format :

```
mysql-bin.00001
mysql-bin.00002
...
mysql-bin.0000n
```

My question is, is there a way to have the binary log file stay the same after each database restart.

So for example it's always mysql-bin.00001

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are five(5) methods you can do

### METHOD #1

Don't run restart. Delete the binlogs between shutdown and startup.

Let's say `mysql-bin.*` is in `/var/lib/mysql`. Run the following:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
service mysql stop
rm -f mysql-bin.*
service mysql start
```

After startup, login to mysql and run

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

an you should see `mysql-bin.000001`

### METHOD #2

Create a script to execute `RESET MASTER;` and have it executed

Step 01 : Add this line to `my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` group header

```
[mysqld]
init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init.sql
```

Step 02 : Run the following

```
echo "RESET MASTER;" > /var/lib/mysql/init.sql
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/init.sql
```

Step 03 : `service mysql restart`

### METHOD #3

Do it by hand. Login to mysql and run

```
mysql> RESET MASTER;
```

### METHOD #4

Erase binary logs immediately after restart

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
service mysql restart
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -e"RESET MASTER"
```

### METHOD #5 (Permanent)

Step 01 : Go to `my.cnf` and comment out the `log-bin` option

```
[mysqld]
#log-bin=mysql-bin
```

or delete the line that says log-bin=mysql-bin

Step 02 : Run the following

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
service mysql stop
rm -f mysql-bin.*
service mysql start
```

Step 03 : Login to mysql and run

```
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

The output should be

```
ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 1):

What is the *real* question?

If you are bothered by more and more binlogs piling up, then configure

```
expire_logs_days = 7
```

That will keep binlogs for only 7 days.  That might be 1 binlog (if you stay up all the time); it might be a hundred (if you restart with ridiculous frequency).  But they won't pile up forever.

I assume you have binlog turned on for some reason -- recovery?  backup?  etc?  Each of those cannot have you blindly throwing away binlogs as Rolando suggests in some of his methods.